# Using Google channel api on the client side by embedding javascript in java using rhino or standard inbuilt javascript support?

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, rhino

I am just experimenting about and I want to know whether it will be possible (and if possible how should I go about it?) to create a desktop client which will use javascript embedded in java using rhino or simply the inbuilt libraries(which are rhino again anyway) to successfully open and maintain an instance of the Channel API for google app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably possible, but only with a great deal of difficulty. The javascript library expects to be run in a browser, so it expects things like the DOM to be available; you may have to provide some or all of this in order to get it to run.

Comment: Will it be possible,say if i use [envjs](http://www.envjs.com/) and [rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)...ive been trying to understand how to use it...unsuccessful so far !